# SQL Server Audit Log

Tags: sql-server

What is the quickest and easiest way to start audit logging on a SQL Server database.

We have a business critical application written in Microsoft Access. We are using a SQL database as the back end. We get many support calls related to bad data due to invalid logic in the access application. To help resolve this issues quickly I want to implement audit tracking.

I investigated Change Tracking feature of SQL but this did not track which user made a change.

Is there any easy way to set up change tracking.

Can you set up a SQL Profile trace that writes to the table via a commandline or sql statement?

Comment: There are many events you can trace with SQL Profiler.  If you play around with the available events you should be able to decide if what you want is available.  It sounds like you think the issue has to do with invalid logic in the Access application.  When you look at the finished SQL data, can you trace back to which logic was exercised?  A SQL Trace won't point out MS Access logic.

Comment: No but I can correlate the SQL statements back to the screens that caused the invalid data. I can also find the user who made the changes and educate them about the impact of making said changes.

Comment: @user3845056 Easiest way with minimal impact  to start auditing what is running is your database is to set up extended events session..